# Running several containers in specific order

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, docker, docker-compose, containers

I am playing around with containers (docker) and I'm trying to create several extraction jobs.

Long story short, currently I have a huge container that runs for several hours doing these extractions.
I want to break this docker image in several minor images, but there is a catch: some of these extractions need to run sequentially. Meaning, for example, that in some cases a given container can only start after a previous one ends.

Is it possible to do this with docker compose? Is there any other solution? I would like to avoid kubernetes and run this on aws or azure ( with azure container instances or aws ecs)?

Thanks

Comment: You are just trying to split a monolithic app into microservices. Expose the APIs for each service and let the services call one another as needed. So, first service, when done, will call the 2nd service and so forth

Comment: I mean, you could just write a shell script that starts your containers in whatever sequence you want.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, split your application into as many components as you need. Ideally, one container should carry out one task only.

Then, given that you want to run the containers sequentially, you should adopt a state machine service. On AWS, you can use [Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html). On Azure, you can use [Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview). With either of these services, you can configure running containers in sequence or even in parallel, as needed.